# Typescript - Display objects by property values

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I got this class:

```
export class ToDoItem {
        id?: number
        description: string
        tags?: string[]
        deadline?: string

        constructor(description: string) {
            this.id = 0
            this.description = description
            this.tags = []
            this.deadline = ""
        }
}
```

And I got this script to display each object of the class, connecting with the HTML:

```
render(items: ToDoItem[]): void {

            this.clearContainer()
            for (const item of items) {
                const template = document.querySelector("#list-item-template") as HTMLTemplateElement
                const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true) as DocumentFragment
                const listItem = clone.querySelector(".list-group-item")
                const checkBox = clone.querySelector(".form-check-input")
                const description = clone.querySelector(".list-item-desc")
                const badgeContainer = clone.querySelector(".badge-container")
                const deadline = clone.querySelector(".list-item-deadline")
                const badgeTemplate = badgeContainer?.querySelector(".list-item-badge")

                checkBox?.setAttribute("data-id", item.id?.toString() || "")
                if (description) {
                    description.textContent = item.description
                }
                if (item.tags) {
                    for (const tag of item.tags) {
                        const newBadge = badgeTemplate?.cloneNode() as Element

                        newBadge.textContent = tag
                        badgeContainer?.append(newBadge)
                    }
                }
                badgeTemplate?.parentElement?.removeChild(badgeTemplate)
                if (deadline) {
                    const date = Date.parse(item.deadline || "")
                    deadline.textContent = (date) ? new Date(date).toUTCString().slice(0,16) : ""
                }
                if (listItem) {
                    this.contentEl?.append(listItem)
                }       
            }
        }
```

But as each object has a list of tags, i wanted to display them by their tags, ex:

Tag1:
item1
item2

Tag2:
item1
item4:

tag3:
item3
item4

Answer (score 0):

You could build a map of the tags:

```js
const items = [
  {label:"item1",tags:["tag1","tag2"]},
  {label:"item2",tags:["tag2","tag3"]},
  {label:"item3",tags:[]},
  {label:"item4"}
];

const tagmap=new Map();
for(let item of items)
  for(let tag of item.tags || [])
    if(tagmap.has(tag))
      tagmap.get(tag).push(item.label);
    else
      tagmap.set(tag,[item.label]);
for(let [k,v] of tagmap.entries())
  console.log(k+": "+v.join());
```

While obviously it's JavaScript code, it also runs on TypeScript Playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), though there may be some nicer constructs in TypeScript, like for handling of the missing tags case.